# Format any number to three digits?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I want to insert any number was entered by the user, to the database like a three digits.

e.g. if the user insert ( 1 ) i want to save the number as ( 001 ), or ( 20 ) to ( 020 ).

note: The data type of the database column is string not integer.

Comment: You do not want to store numbers as strings. It may seem to you that you  need this, but you don't.

Comment: What's seems to be the problem? [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
int iVal = 1;

iVal.ToString("D3"); // = "001"
```

Read more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
 int value =5;
 Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("000"));
 Console.WriteLine(value.ToString().PadLeft(3,'0'));
```

produces:

> 005
>
> 005